# Setting a SOAP Test Request's WSS-Password Type with Groovy

Tags: soap, groovy, soapui, ws-security

In SoapUI 4.5.2, I can generally get & set test-request properties with Groovy in a test-case setup script (e.g. `someTestRequestStep.getPropertyValue("Password")` and `someTestRequestStep.setPropertyValue("Password", "S0mePassw0rd")`)...except for the *WSS-Password Type* property.

`someTestRequestStep.getPropertyValue("WSS-Password Type")` simply returns `null` and `someTestRequestStep.getPropertyList()` does not include a property named `WSS-Password Type` (or anything like it that I see).

`someTestRequestStep.setPropertyValue("WSS-Password Type", "PasswordText")` does not produce an error...but also does not affect the *WSS-Password Type* property of the referenced test request that I see in the GUI.

Also, I have explored `someTestRequestStep.getModelItem().getSettings()` a bit for a solution: no luck thus far.

How can I set the *WSS-Password Type* property of a SoapUI test request with Groovy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to this](http://verygood.www.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?t=13086), you should try:

```
someTestRequestStep.getHttpRequest().setWssPasswordType( "PasswordText" )
```

Or (more groovily):

```
someTestRequestStep.httpRequest.wssPasswordType = 'PasswordText'
```

Comment: That works.  Excellent find.  One potentially confusing thing I noticed is that if my startup script  does not set another test-request property (e.g. _Password_), the new _WSS-Password Type_ value does not show in the GUI right away (i.e. vs. a `setPropertyValue` change like `setPropertyValue("Password", "S0mePassw0rd")` that shows immediately).  `setPropertyValue` seems to trigger a refresh of test-request properties in the GUI whereas `setWssPasswordType` does not.  To see the solo-updated _WSS-Password Type_, I clicked on another test-request property afterward.